# Пытаюсь получить статус пользователя по сообщению бота(аиограм +пирограм)

Tags: python, aiogram, pyrogram

Пытаюсь сделать следующее:

```
async def checkuser(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите юзернейм пользователя")
    id = message.text
    with app:
        g = app.get_users("hankipoiii").status
        print(g)
    if g== "online":
        timewentonline = datetime.datetime.now()
        goodtime = datetime.datetime.today()
        while g == "online":

            timewentoff = datetime.datetime.now()
            alltime = round((timewentoff - timewentonline).total_seconds())
        if alltime >= 60:
            await message.answer(
                f"Пользователь с username {id} был онлайн в {goodtime}\nВремя, проведенное онлайн: {alltime / 60} минут")
        if alltime >= 3600:
            await message.answer(
                f"Пользователь с username {id} был онлайн в {goodtime}\nВремя, проведенное онлайн: {alltime / 3600} часов")
        else:
            await message.answer(
                f"Пользователь с username {id} был онлайн в {goodtime}\nВремя, проведенное онлайн: {alltime} секунд")
```

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'status'

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция app.get_users() - асинхронная, Вы забыли ключевое слово `await`, для вызова асинхронной функции:

```py
with app:
    g = await app.get_users("hankipoiii")
    status = g.status
    print(status)
```